# Repeating a mongo document with new date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an event calendar for a client in React with a Mongo DB. On the public facing side the users will be able to view events, and add them to their calendar on their phone, which I have working. The problem I ran into is that the events rarely change from week to week, if they do its probably the name of an instructor, or a change of rooms. So on the Admin side, when the Admin creates an event they will be able to click Recurring Event until "X" date. On the server I need the document to be recreated until the Start Time or End Time of the event is equal to the date of the recur till date.

my Schema for an event looks like this:

```
var activitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "room": String,
    "type": String,
    "title" : String,
    "start": {type: Date},
    "end": {type: Date},
    "instructor" : String,
    "desc": String,
    "image": String,
    "style": {
        "backgroundColor": String
    }
})
```

and when a user hits submit on the creation form this is what fires:

```
onSubmit() {
    var startTime = {start: this.state.start || this.state.data};
    var endTime = {end: this.state.end || this.state.data};
    var color = {style: {backgroundColor: this.state.color || this.state.data}}
    var image ={image: this.state.image || this.state.data};

    var myForm = this.refs.MyForm.getValue();
    var payload = _.merge(myForm, startTime, endTime, color, image);
    if (payload._id) {
        superagent.put("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/activity/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
            err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
        });
    } else {
        delete payload._id; //remove the empty id object from the post since it's blank.
        superagent.post("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/activity/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
            err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
            this.refs.MyForm.reset();
        });
    }
},
```

So what I need to happen is when they hit submit, it will repeat the document over and over again, but with the date increased by 7 days, so its repeated every week on the same day of the week.

Right now it is just creating one event at a time, for the selected date and time, and displaying on the calendar as such. I am using MomentJS for the time handling, I was going to try and use Moment-Recur, but there is a error when installing it, but it seems to be a common problem that hasn't been resolved yet.

Any help, or suggestions, would be awesome, I am not a Back-End guy, and at a loss on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving my issue. While it may not be the best way to do repeating of events, it's what i've been told to do my multiple people around me.

```
if(this.refs.repeatCheckbox.checked){
      //let endRepeat = moment().endOf("month").format();
      let endRepeat = moment(this.state.repeat).add({days: 1}).format();
      let start = moment(this.state.start).format();
      let end = moment(this.state.end).format();

      do {
        let newStart = {start: start};
        let newEnd = {end: end};

        var myForm = this.refs.MyForm.getValue();
        var payload = _.merge(myForm, newStart, newEnd, color, image);

        if (payload._id) {
            superagent.put("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/activity/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
                err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
            });
        } else {
            delete payload._id; //remove the empty id object from the post since it's blank.
            superagent.post("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/activity/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
                err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
                this.refs.MyForm.reset();
            });
        }

        start = moment(start).add({days: 7}).format();
        end = moment(end).add({days: 7}).format();
      } while (end < endRepeat);
    } else {
      var myForm = this.refs.MyForm.getValue();
      var payload = _.merge(myForm, startTime, endTime, color, image);

      if (payload._id) {
          superagent.put("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/activity/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
              err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
          });
      } else {
          delete payload._id; //remove the empty id object from the post since it's blank.
          superagent.post("http://"+this.context.config.API_SERVER+"/api/v1.0/activity/").send(payload).end((err, res) => {
              err ? console.log(err) : console.log(res);
              this.refs.MyForm.reset();
          });
      }
    };
```

so if the user checked the repeat box, and enters the date they wish to repeat til, it will loop over the submit function and add 7 days until the end date equals the chosen repeat date. if they don't check the box and choose a date, it will just create the one event. Might not be the best solution, but it works, and it works with the calendar I am using.

Answer (score 0):

We had very similar requirements and ended up using this npm package:

https://github.com/tritech/node-icalendar

This allows to manage real iCal objects, that are recognized by typical calendar applications like Outlook, Google Calendar and such. Is supports recurring events, so you only need one event object with a recurrence definition. 
If you need the occurences of a recurring event there is a `getOccurences()` function. Unfortunately there is very little documentation, the unit tests are the best place to start.

You might have to rethink your data model of events though - in the world of iCal, Outlook, ... a recurring event is only one event, not multiple.

On the client side (web app) we used this service: `https://www.addevent.com/` to allow a user to add a recurring event to his calendar.

Comment: for adding the event to the users calendar, we used [https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) since this is a hybrid app, which I forgot to say, I apologize. I am not worried about the event recurring on the users phone, I can add that in with the Cordova plugin. On the calendar on the app/admin panel the event only shows once since the component we used [https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar) pulls in the data from Mongo.

Comment: I looked through the code of that component "react-big-calendar". It is very unfortunate that it does not support recurring events. In my opinion it is not a good solution to duplicate your event in the database - your display component should simply support to display recurring events. How would you ever maintain your duplicates when the original changes... Maybe you should better look for a calendar component that supports recurring events.